# How to store Objects in Android so that they are accessible even when app restarts

Tags: android, sqlite, storage

I am developing an Android Application for Home Automation.
I am creating objects for each device(home appliance) which has different data fields such as device name, device ID and device status etc. 
I want to store these object data in android storage so that even when I restart my app I can access these data.

I researched and found that Internal Storage and SQLite are 2 methods which can be used to store this type of data.
Which method is more suitable in this application?

Comment: what kind of object is it? what does it contains ?

Comment: Use shared preferences if data is limited.

Comment: It is an object(Instance) of a simple java class which I have created.

Comment: @sanatshukla but Shared Preferences can store data in form of Key value Pairs only.

Comment: @vipin If it is limited then store it individually with key and value.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

You can store your java objects in the bundle of onSaveInstanceState() as a Parcelable object. But your model class will have to implement Parcelable interface.

After you have implemented Parcelable interface in your model class, Override the onSaveInstanceState() method in your activity/fragment:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(OBJ_KEY,yourObject);
}
```

Now, in your onCreate method get the value from bundle:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            yourPreservedObj = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(OBJ_KEY);//when your app re starts you have your object here.

        }
}
```

Comment: but are savedInstanceStates accessible if I close and restart the app?

Comment: Nope, not if the app was really closed

Comment: In that case my friend, the best option is to use SQLite db. Serialize ur obj into byte stream and store it.